# how to define the method nextint() for the type scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I write a program about scanner according to the instructions in books,however it fails to compile.The explanation provided by eclipse is that nextint() is undefined.I don't know how to define nextint().Could anyone help me with that?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class ReadTwoNums{
        public static void main(String[] args){
        int num1,num2,sum;
        Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input the first the integer");
        num1=keyboard.nextint();
        System.out.print("Input the second the integer");
        double dollars=keyboard.nextDouble();
        num2=keyboard.nextint();
        sum=num1+num2;
        System.out.println("The sum is"+sum);
        }
    }


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation  problems: 
The method nextint() is undefined for the type Scanner
The method nextint() is undefined for the type Scanner

at exercise.ReadTwoNums.main(ReadTwoNums.java:8)
```

Comment: it is `nextInt()`  uppercase `I`

Comment: Thanks,I forget that java is uppercase sensitive.

Answer (score -1):

nextInt() is case sensitive

Try  keyboard.nextInt();

Answer (score -1):

Java is case sensitive

it is supposed to be `Keyboard.nextInt()` instead of nextint(). Do it like you did in `keyboard.nextDouble()`

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class ReadTwoNums{
        public static void main(String[] args){
        int num1,num2,sum;
        Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input the first the integer");
        num1=keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Input the second the integer");
        double dollars=keyboard.nextDouble();
        num2=keyboard.nextInt();
        sum=num1+num2;
        System.out.println("The sum is "+sum);
        }
    }//end of class ReadTwoNums
```